# Seaborn Matplotlib Python - How to annotate heatmap if value > x

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I've figured out there is an option for a seaborn heatmap which adds the values to the corresponding fields in the map `annot=True`. Now I'm wondering if there is an opportunity to only annotate the fields with the values if the value reached a specific threshold.

If not, is there a solution for this problem using matplotlib?

Regards

Comment: Check [Creating annotated heatmaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html). You can adapt the function to your needs.

Comment: @SamSampleman did you find a solution that you could share?